# How to make custom QWidget receive all key press events, even shortcuts of global actions?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

In Qt 5, assume the following custom widget:

```
class QMeow final :
    public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit QMeow()
    {
        this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    }

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * const event) override
    {
        _s = !_s;
        this->update();
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override
    {
        QPainter painter {this};

        painter.fillRect(this->rect(), QColor {_s ? "red" : "blue"});
    }

private:
    bool _s = false;
};
```

An instance of this widget changes its background color between red and blue when any key is pressed.

Now, let's make a window and add a `QLineEdit` as well as a `QMeow`, also setting an action with the shortcut key **A**:

```
QApplication app {argc, argv};
QWidget window;
QVBoxLayout layout {&window};

layout.addWidget(new QLineEdit);
layout.addWidget(new QMeow);

QAction action {"hello"};

action.setShortcut(Qt::Key_A);
window.addAction(&action);

window.show();
app.exec();
```

If you try this, you'll notice that:

- When the `QLineEdit` widget has the focus, it handles all the keys, including lowercase **A**, adding it to its rendered text.
- When the `QMeow` widget has the focus, it handles all the keys *except* lowercase **A**, suggesting that the action handles it instead.

How can `QMeow::keyPressEvent()` get called for any key, including action shortcuts, like `QLineEdit`?

I tried `QWidget::grabKeyboard()`, different focus policies, and looking at `qlineedit.cpp` without success.

Comment: Ok, I got this. But, before answering, an important question: why are you trying to use no-modifier shortcuts? They are normally discouraged (especially for alphanumeric characters), as they can be very ambiguous. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My main window has a single text input widget, which is this custom one I'm writing, and it's only visible on demand. Everything else keyboard-wise goes to actions. And then I personally prefer pressing **A** than **Ctrl** + **A**.

Comment: And what prevents you to use a QLineEdit? Sorry for looking pedantic, but I've seen similar requests, and most of the times they end up being XY problems.

Comment: Let's just pretend this is an educational project to learn custom widgets creation and I'm now writing my own `QLineEdit`-like one. I'm not officially recommanding this to anyone.

Comment: Ok, seems reasonable; not knowing your experience (especially with Qt), I just wanted to be sure, as I've seen tons of posts asking about intricate solutions just because they've been asking themselves the wrong question. I've been writing an answer anyway in the meantime, I just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text input widgets in Qt normally use an internal "text control" which is used as a "proxy" for any text-related aspect, including keyboard input.

A focused widget always receives a special `ShortcutOverride` event (a QKeyEvent) whenever it may trigger a shortcut valid for the current context.

See the relevant documentation about [`QEvent::ShortcutOverride`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum):

> Key press in child, for overriding shortcut key handling ([QKeyEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html)). When a shortcut is about to trigger, `ShortcutOverride` is sent to the active window. This allows clients (e.g. widgets) to signal that they will handle the shortcut themselves, by accepting the event. If the shortcut override is accepted, the event is delivered as a normal key press to the focus widget. Otherwise, it triggers the shortcut action, if one exists.

Similarly, the related section of the [QKeyEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#details) docs:

> For QEvent::ShortcutOverride the receiver needs to explicitly accept the event to trigger the override. Calling ignore() on a key event will propagate it to the parent widget. The event is propagated up the parent widget chain until a widget accepts it or an event filter consumes it.

This is exactly what text input widgets do: they override `event()` ([`QLineEdit::event()`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp.html#1490)) and send `ShortcutOverride` events to the internal text control object ([`QWidgetLineControl::processShortcutOverrideEvent()`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp.html#_ZN18QWidgetLineControl28processShortcutOverrideEventEP9QKeyEvent)), which contains the following:

```cpp
...
} else if (ke->modifiers() == Qt::NoModifier || ke->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier
           || ke->modifiers() == Qt::KeypadModifier) {
    if (ke->key() < Qt::Key_Escape) {
        if (!isReadOnly())
            ke->accept();
...
```

Since standard alphanumeric keys are below `Qt::Key_Escape` (`0x01000000`, and the `Qt::Key` enum mostly uses the standard ASCII numeration for them, with upper case for letters) this means that shortcuts using such keys are always accepted if they don't have modifiers, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> or are pressed within the numeric pad. The result is that they *accept* the shortcut, preventing propagation to parents, which will then be "converted" to a standard `KeyPress` and eventually sent to the `keyPressEvent()` handler.

The solution is then to override `event()`, check for `ShortcutOverride` events, and accept it (assuming you *do* want to accept such key press).

Comment: Overriding `QWidget::event()` to accept the event when its type is `QEvent::ShortcutOverride`, and then unconditionally forwarding to `QWidget::event()` works perfectly!